# Is there a setting where we can specify which field the cursor lands in for Harmon.ie

Tags: harmon.ie

Users are asking if we can manage where the cursor lands for harmon.ie checkins of emails and/or attachments.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to control on which field the focus will in our edit properties window.
The logic is as follow.
In case there is no required fields:
-The focus will be on the first empty field
In case there are required fields:
-The focus will be on the first empty required fields.

---- Jean